# fullpage.js effect in a container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullpage.js, jquery-scrollify

From a quick search here and in Google I realised that it is not possible to put fullpage.js in a container, hence the name **full**page.js

Unfortunately I have to find a solution for my project. I want normal scroll on my entire website, but a specific div should have the fullpage.js "slideshow" effect, that when you scroll a bit, the whole section is moving to the other direction. I tried doing it myself with a lot of javascript calculations (scroll direction, binding and unbinding scroll events etc), but Its out of the scope of this project budget.

So my question is: is there a way to hack it around with fullpage.js or maybe with another plugin? I found scrollify, but it is basically the same.

Here is an HTML Code to show exactly what I mean

```
<body>
   <h1>Some website</h1>
   <h2>I want to scroll it normal</h2>
   <div id="fullpage">
    <!-- Only here should the slides scroll with the desired effect -->
      <div class="section"></div>
      <div class="section"></div>
      <div class="section"></div>
    </div>    
</body>
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Here is a [video](https://youtu.be/oTYKdzYcbM4) showing exactly what am looking for.

Comment: The most you can do with fullPage.js is make use of the `scrollOverflow` feature as [in this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html). This would emulate the behaviour of a normal scroll in a site for your first section, then you can have the rest of sections with the fullPage.js effect.

Comment: As an example of usage, take a look at the 5th section in [this site](https://sourcetoyou.com/) using a small viewport. They are using `scrollOverflow` but they hidden the scrollbar.

Comment: What im looking for is something like this: https://youtu.be/oTYKdzYcbM4